# Create a dynamic array of strings that will scale upon being filled up

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic-arrays, realloc

Okay, so I'm reading though a txt file and storing each item by new line into an array of strings. The only problem is, I need to resize this array by 5 whenever it is close to filling up.

Input looks something like this, except a lot larger

```
CSE 1104
CSE 1105
CSE 1310
CSE 2320
IE 2308
PHYS 1443
MATH 1426
```

Here is my code

```
void printFileError(char *s) {
    printf("unable to open %s\n", s);
    exit(1);
}

void reallocTaken(char **taken, int *size, int newSize) {
    (*size) = newSize;
    taken = realloc(taken, (*size) * sizeof(char *));
    printf("Realocateding---- \n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **coursesTaken;
    int coursesTakenSize = 5;

    int i;

    char *filePlan, *fileMyCourses;
    FILE *fp;

    /* Open the file of completed courses */
    if((fp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) != NULL) {
        char buffer[255];
        int lineCount = 0;

        coursesTaken = malloc(sizeof(char *) * coursesTakenSize);

        while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) {
            char token[] = "\n";
            char *split = strtok(buffer, token);

            while(split != NULL) {

                /* Check if array is full */
                if((lineCount + 1) == coursesTakenSize) {
                    printf("Needs to allocate \n");
                    /* Realoc Memory */
                    reallocTaken(coursesTaken, &coursesTakenSize, coursesTakenSize + 5);
                }

                coursesTaken[lineCount] = malloc((sizeof(split) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(coursesTaken[lineCount], split);

                printf("%s\n", split);

                lineCount++;
                split = strtok(NULL, token);
            }
        }

        /* Cut out exessive memory */
        reallocTaken(coursesTaken, &coursesTakenSize, lineCount);

        printf("Line Count: %d\n", lineCount);
        printf("Size: %d\n", coursesTakenSize);
        printf("Final Size: %lu\n", sizeof(coursesTaken));
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        printFileError(argv[2]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < coursesTakenSize; i++) {
        printf("%d:\t%s\n", i+1, coursesTaken[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The plan here was to 
first allocate the 5 slots of memory and when the line count becomes equal to the size, add 5 more slots to it. After the file is done, resize the whole thing to the number of lines. At the same time, allocate each index of the array, the fill it with the data from the text file.

The code successfully reallocates the first two blocks, then gives the error

```
a.out(9410,0x7fff7f20a300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fcb9b404bb0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
```

That happens here

```
CSE 1104
CSE 1105
CSE 1310
CSE 2320
Needs to allocate 
Realocateding---- 
IE 2308
PHYS 1443
MATH 1426
MATH 1302
MATH 1323
Needs to allocate
```

I noticed by commenting `coursesTaken[lineCount] = malloc((sizeof(split) + 1) * sizeof(char))` the program fully runs until the end when print each

I'm not really too sure what's going on here.

Comment: You are searching for `realloc()`.

Comment: @iharob Yes, I am using that, do i need to be using that for allocating each string as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a confusion between `sizeof`, which can give the size on a single element, of a struct, or of **an array whose size is known**, and `strlen` which gives the len of a null terminated string.

The line `coursesTaken[lineCount] = malloc((sizeof(split) + 1) * sizeof(char))`, is indeed the culprit. As in next line you copy `split` into that, you need that it can contains all characters in split plus the terminating null.

But as `split` is a `char *`, `sizeof(split)` is **the size of a pointer** (that is for example 4 on a 32 bits system, and 8 on a 64 one).

You should write this line :

```
coursesTaken[lineCount] = malloc((strlen(split) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
void reallocTaken(char ***taken, int *size, int newSize) {
    (*size) = newSize;
    *taken = realloc(*taken, (*size) * sizeof(char *));
    printf("Realocateding---- \n");
}
```

and to call it so:

```
    reallocTaken(&coursesTaken, &coursesTakenSize, coursesTakenSize + 5);
```

In your original code, you are losing the pointer to the reallocated space by assigning it to `taken` instead of `*taken`, and instead continuing to use a pointer to the original, at that point freed, space.  The principle is the same as the one you correctly apply to `courseTakenSize`.

When you try to reallocate that original pointer again, the error you report follows.